# Creating a new column to find the range of date

Tags: python, pandas, date-range

I am working on a data frame which contains date.
I want to create a new column to classify the period of the date in a year. That means that I will assume as every 2 months as a range. But my starting date will be  August. THus,

```
Aug to Sep is 1,
Oct to Nov is 2,
Dec to Jan is 3,
Feb to Mar is 4 and
Apr to May is 5.
```

The sample date is as follow:

```
data =pd.DataFrame()
data ['Date'] = ['27-03-2019','08-10-2019','09-04-2019','09-08-2018']
data.period = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'])
```

The expected outcome as range in a new column would be as follow:

[image]

Can anyone advise me how to do that?

Thanks a lot

Zep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try create dictionary with [`numpy.roll`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html), [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html), [`numpy.arange`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) and last use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`Series.dt.month`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.month.html):

```
a = np.arange(1, 13)
b = np.roll(np.repeat(np.arange(1,7), 2), 7)
d = dict(zip(a, b))
print (d)
{1: 3, 2: 4, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 6, 8: 1, 9: 1, 10: 2, 11: 2, 12: 3}

df['Range'] = df['Date'].dt.month.map(d)
print (df)
        Date  Range
0 2019-03-27      4
1 2019-10-08      2
2 2019-04-09      5
3 2018-08-09      1
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import pandas as pd
df =pd.DataFrame()
df ['Date'] = ['27-03-2019','10-08-2019','04-09-2019','08-09-2018']
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])


month_range={8:1,9:1,10:2,11:2,12:3,1:3,2:4,3:4,4:5,5:5,6:6,7:6}

df['Range'] = [month_range.get(d) for d in df['Date'].dt.month]
```

Ouput:

```
    Date        Range
0   2019-03-27   4
1   2019-10-08   2
2   2019-04-09   5
3   2018-08-09   1
```

Comment: Thanks Min2bro. Appreciate your advice